# How to get a user's group list in c++ cross platform?

Tags: c++

It looks like the different Unix Oses don't follow any standard method for obtaining a user's groups. GNU uses getgrouplist and aix uses getgrset. What would I use on HPUX, Solaris, or Mac?

Edit:
I'm looking to be able to pass in a username, and get a list of the groups. So, getgroups wont work (since it only provides the groups of the calling process uid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at /etc/group and search for the username of the user. The group will be at the beginning of the line before the colon.

example:

```
wheel:x:10:username
```

Comment: I'd rather not re-implement the getgrouplist functionality, but I guess I will if I have to.

Comment: FYI, that doesn't work on Mac anyway (there is no /etc/group).

Comment: If you go about parsing the group file (wherever it is) anyway you could directly use `getgrent` which is in POSIX.

Comment: I ended up just going through the groups using getgrent and implemented my own getgrouplist.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the [`groups`](http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/The_Groups_Command.html) command that outputs the current user's groups to stdout. You can run that.

Run `groups <username>` and look at its output.

Comment: I'm looking for the correct way to do this in c++, not parsing command line output.

Comment: `getresuid` does the same, but it can only query the GID of the calling process.

Comment: You can run `groups` from your C++ code and read its output. As you've said yourself, there's no standard API for this.